# OpenCart : Extract Orders Details in Database

Tags: php, opencart

I know I can extract Sales Order data in OpenCart database, in table `shop_order` and `shop_order_product`.

Is it possible to differentiate which user creates the sales order?

Comment: By user u meant customer ? Or order created from admin side?

Comment: Order created from Admin side. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an option to identify which admin user created the order. You may need to code it yourself. The below steps may help you.

1. Add 2 new fields `created_user_id` and `updated_user_id` in `order` table - with default value as 0.
2. Update the `admin/model/sale/order.php` to insert values to those fields as `$this->user->getId();`  (`addOrder` and `editOrder` functions ).
3. Add a new field `user_id` in `order_history` table - with default value as 0.
4. Update the `admin/model/sale/order.php`  to insert value to that field as `$this->user->getId();` (function: `addOrderHistory`).

You can do these by directly modifying the files or using vqmod. If it's done via vqmod then it'll be easier for you to make changes during opencart version upgrade.
**[Opencart: Vqmod tutorial](https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/)**

Have a nice day!!

Comment: I have to re-do this when OpenCart updates its version?

Comment: Then do it using vqmod. Please find my updated answer.

Comment: I finished installing the vQmod, but I'm still confused with the vQmod XML configuration file. How can I transform your instructions above to the XML ?

Comment: Please try the code under `Sample vqmod xml file:` in that link. The same way you can modify other files.

Answer (score 1):

By default, there's no way to know which admin an order is created by, or even that the order isn't created by the user (other than the IP would be that of the admin). You could in theory add the `user_id` to the `shop_order` table, and pass that to the manual order editor when it creates the orders

Comment: Clarify: I have to manually create an extra field in "shop_orders" table and pass the "active user" variable when saving the order? So, when the OpenCart version is updated, the changes will be broken?

Comment: If you do this via vQmod, then the changes should not be removed when you upgrade no. The table itself will retain the information regardless. And yes you pass the `$this->user->getId()`; value from the admin to the catalog side, just like the rest of the variables get passed in the order editor

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to OpenCart. Is this [vQmod](https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/) you're talking about?

Comment: yes. You should use that instead of making any core file changes for any edits